# Access Trix config in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, trix

I would like to access the `Trix` object in my Angular app to make some modifications to the config object.

I tried

```
import { Trix } from '../../../../node_modules/trix/';
```

```
import * as Trix from '../../../../node_modules/trix/';
```

```
import { Trix } from '../../../../node_modules/trix/dist/trix.js';
```

```
import * as Trix from '../../../../node_modules/trix/dist/trix.js';
```

and every possible variation, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth, it's Angular 7

Comment: Thanks, but that question is about using Trix, I got it up and running, but I need to access the configure variable